# String/Strap attached to Christian McBride's bass?

Tags: jazz, double-bass

I've seen some images/videos where his bass has a black string wrapped around it and was curious if anyone knows what its purpose is:

[image]

Video:

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like he has a soft pad between the body and his hip/abdomen.  The strap just holds it in place

Comment: It looks like a band to hold the soft pad in place in this case. At first glance I thought it may have been one of these https://www.thomann.de/gb/headway_the_band_double_bass_pickup.html, which a friend of mine used. It's a pickup that tries to get the sound of the whole bass, rather than the rather nasal tone of many bridge-based pickups. But in this case I think Carl is right, it's just a strap!

Comment: The purpose of the cloth or pad is for protecting the instrument from buttons, zippers, belt buckles, etc. that the player might have on his clothes. Ron Carter also uses one. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ron_Carter#/media/File:Ron_Carter_Berkeley1.jpg